# Bootcamp Problem. Unable to partition the disk

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, high-sierra, apfs

I'm using a Macbook pro 13 (2015) with 256G SSD. High Sierra 10.13.1.

I'm trying to use bootcamp to install a windows 10 on my laptop.But I encountered the following problem.

[image]
[image]

I tried to delete snapshots of Time Machine as told by an answer [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8086777?start=0&tstart=0), but it didn't work.

So I wonder if there is any other solutions than erase the whole disk? I thought this should have relationship with the APFS file systems?

Looking for your help!

Answer (score 6):

So, looks like Bootcamp can't properly partiton your solid state drive.

***If something doesn’t work, comment it so I can fix it.***

> Before continuing, **make sure that you have a backup!!!** I am not responsible for any damage caused by this guide. *You have been warned.*

**These two steps are required for both methods, so do them.**

***Step 1:*** Open **Disk Utility** inside **"Other" folder** in the **Launchpad**, or simply type **Disk Utility** inside **Spotlight**.

***Step 2:*** Select **APPLE SSD SM02...** (if you changed the name over the time, select your disk instead) from the list at the left, but **NOT the containers**, and press **Partition** located at the top.

From here, choose one of these methods to continue. **Method 3 is the best method if you only have one partition, but if you have more than one, such as Linux DualBoot, then go for Method 1.**

> **Method 1 (Manually installing Windows 10, Better for your case)**

***Step 3:*** A pie of your disk should have appeared now. From here, select your macOS partition and click **+ (plus)** button. There is a new partition now. Arrange it's size either **from the properties**, or **by dragging it from the borders**. This is going to be your Windows 10 partition. Give it at least 40GBs of size and **leave at least 10GBs of space for macOS**. Name the new partition (not macOS partition) with a name that **you will remember**, such as **BOOTCAMP**, but make sure it is **all in capital letters**. Lastly set it's type as **MS-DOS (FAT)** and press **Apply**. You'll be warned that you are resizing your boot partition, just press **OK**.

***You need a USB formatted as FAT32 with at least 8 GBs of free space to continue...***

***Step 4:*** After you have created your Windows partition, download and install unetbootin from [here](http://unetbootin.github.io/). Then run it and select **Disk Image** option on the screen. Select ISO option from the dropdown menu next to Disk Image text if it is not already selected. Then press the button with **three dots (...)** and select your **Windows ISO image** (assuming you already have one). Lastly, select your USB from the dropdown menu next to **Drive** text and press **OK**. This will burn the ISO image to the USB.

***Step 4.1:*** To learn what your USB is called, open up a **Terminal** from Spotlight and type:

```
diskutil list
```

This will show you all of the drives connected to your computer. Your USB is something like /dev/disk1s1 or /dev/disk1s2 (but **definitely not /dev/disk0**). You can understand which one is your USB by searching for your USB's label.

***Step 5:*** Now open up the Bootcamp assistant for the last time. Once it's opened, select **Action > Download Windows Helper Software** or something like that. This will download Bootcamp helper. Select the target as your desktop and continue.

***Step 6:*** Once your bootcamp software is downloaded and unetbootin is done, copy the **WindowsSupport** folder from your desktop to the USB's root directory.

***Step 7:*** It's time to begin the installation! Reboot your MacBook and when it's powering on, press and hold **Alt (option)** key on your keyboard. Once a menu with boot options appear, select the **EFI Boot** or **Windows** option with a USB icon on it. This will start the installer. Give it a few minutes and once the button to begin the installation appears, press it. Wait for it to start. Once it started, select **Special** option. ***This part is important!!!*** A list of volumes should have appeared now. Select the partition you created earlier for Windows and click **Format**. When it's done, re-select the Windows partition and press **Install**. Now just relax and wait for it to finish.

***Step 8:*** After you fully setup Windows, select your USB from Windows Explorer and go to WindowsSupport folder. In that folder, run the **setup** program. Install it as a normal program and you are done!

> **Method 2 (Removing any partition other than your macOS partition)**
>
> **Be careful!** Doing this will destroy any data on any other partition that is not macOS partition. I do not recommend this method since there is no way to know if Bootcamp assistant will be fixed or not. Also this method may not be helpful for you since you only have one partition.

Sometimes Bootcamp fails to partition the drive itself (which does this method automatically) and you need to do it manually to continue.

***Step 3:*** **This step may be dangerous if not done properly, so be careful!** A pie of your disk should have appeared now. From here, delete every other partition that are not your macOS partition one by one by pressing the **- (minus)** button. After you are done, press **Apply**.

**If step 3 failed,** try it again. It usually fails at first try.

**If the only partition is macOS partition,** try method 1 instead.

***Step 4:*** Now try running Bootcamp assistant again. If this method didn't fix your problem, try method 1 instead.

> **Method 3 (Converting APFS back to HFS+, best for everyone)**

***Step 3:*** Backup your installation with **Time machine** (but not any other software). *This is not optional.*

***Step 4:*** Reboot your computer into recovery mode. To do this, press **Command+R** after you hear the startup chime.

***Step 5:*** You will be presented with a list of some utilities. Select **Disk Utility**.

***Step 6:*** In the disk utility, select “Macintosh HD” (or your system partition) and select **Erase**. Select **Mac OS Extended (Journaled)** as the type and select **Erase**.

***Step 7:*** Quit the disk utility. From the list, select **Restore from Time Machine backup**. Go through the instructions and restore your backup to disk.

***Step 8:*** After you restarted your machine, retry the Bootcamp Utility. It should work now. If not, try method 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot！ Sorry to respond you late. I think the second method does not work, because I cannot see other volumes so that it is impossible to erase them. Finally, I erase the whole disk in Diskutility and install it back by Time Machine. And it did works!

Comment: Nice to see that I helped you. If you didn’t try method 1, then you probably converted APFS to HFS+ after restoring from time machine, which fixed BootCamp. (I never thought about the conversion method actually. I will update my answer)

Comment: The third option doesn't seem to work if yoiu have 10.13.3. The only options after hitting erase are all some form of apfs, just to make sure any fixes to boot camp performing poorly were adequately trashed.